# Force Interface orientation Landscape on a viewController when the rest of the application is in portrait mode

Tags: iphone, ios5, interface-builder, orientation

Good evening all!
I am developing an application in Portait orientation and i was wander if there is a way for me to change the orientation of only one view to landspace left without messing with the rest of the app.

I tried returning

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
  //return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

but with no luck... In IB the orientation for the View controller is set to landscape but when i run the app, it keeps appearing in portrait mode... Also tried setting the

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
```

with no luck...

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft]; it  give warning,but it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me was using

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

in my ViewController and presenting it with ***presentModalViewController***.
This forces the View to stay in landscape.

Comment: Nice One! Thanks... The only problem is that it would be good for me to keep it inside the NavigationController... It may be impossible though... Thanks again!

Comment: Nice! thank you very much ! but what does method `shouldAutorotate` mean ?

Answer (score 3):

You can manually set the transform of the view to rotate it. For example, to rotate 90 degrees:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI / 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

Write in your Event.